# Форматирование строк print() в Python, как это работает?

Tags: python

Есть программа вывода таблицы умножения через цикл for, хотел чтоб программа выводила таблицу умножения как в школе на тетрадке(столбцами, если кто помнит). Я добился результата, но когда сделал я вообще не понял как это работает. Я запутался. Я экспериментировал с  параметром end='' функции print, потом в конце программы после второго for просто поставил пустую print() и вывод стал правильным. Получается я просто наугад это сделал подставляя всё в подряд. Кто может объяснить как это вообще работает?
Вот код:

```
a = list(range(2, 10))
b = list(range(2, 10))
print("                                         Таблица умножения                   ")
for i in a:
    for j in b:
        print(f"{j} * {i} ={i*j:3}", end='   ')
    print()
```

[image: Правильный вывод программы, если убираю последний пустой print() или end=' ' всё ломается]

Comment: По умолчанию у `print` параметр `end='\n'`, поэтому любой `print(...)` переводит строку, если не указано другое в параметре `end=`. Ну вот у вас пустой `print()` строку и перевёл, как вам и нужно было. Для этого пустой `print()` в коде бывает используют после цикла, это только в первый раз удивительно.

Comment: Спасибо, я тут еще с циклами тупил думал как printd в них  работает, сейчас вроде только понял как он всё выводит. Сейчас вроде понял